# Express.js : json data is not returned completely

Tags: node.js, json, express, backend

I am developing an API for a chart that contains large JSON data, and sometimes JSON is not returned completely.
If I reload the API again after some reload, data is returned completely.

### In the chrome network tab, I usually got

> failed to load response data: no data found for a resource with the given identifier.

## [image]

### In the firefox network tab, I got the error as:

[image]
[image: It is not completely returned]

Comment: That is unfortunate. Without any context it will be difficult to help. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: What is the content length? What is the actual length? Can we get the original string? Do you have any special characters?

Comment: I have updated the questions.

Comment: Do you want to know (a) why the server does not reliably return complete JSON or (b) why different browsers display this differently in their network tab? In case of (a), we need more information about the server-side code.